# 'System.web.HttpException Resource cannot be found' error in first time using visual studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, macos, mono

I have used visual studio in windows before but this is my very first using IOS and I am getting error in the first time running of my asp.net file. I have checked all the possible dependancies but nothing is wrong. My Globel.asax file doesn't seems to be problem but I am not sure about my web.confing. Here is the error page that I am getting;

> System.Web.HttpException
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Details: Requested URL: /
>
> Exception stack trace:
>
> at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00094] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/StaticFileHandler.cs:77 
>     at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0007f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/DefaultHttpHandler.cs:101 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication+d__225.MoveNext () [0x008d4] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1335 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:927

This is my aspx file and haven't code for cs file yet.

```
`<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="fyp_codes.Login" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="formclass">
            <asp:Image runat="server" imageURL="~/images/PlantManager.jfif" width="200px"/>
            <asp:Image ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" imageURL="~/images/quote.jfif" height="128px" />
            <asp:Image runat="server" imageURL="~/images/TeamLogo.jfif" width="126px"/>


            <div style="text-align:right">
                <a href="aboutus.html" class="text-muted" target="_blank">About Plant Manager</a>
                <!–– href replace to other pages, blank: open in new tab ––>

            </div>


            <asp:label> <b> Username </b> </asp:label>
            <asp:TextBox id="TxtName" CssClass="input" placeholder="Enter Username" runat="server"/>

            <asp:label> <b> Password </b> </asp:label>
            <asp:TextBox id="TxtPsw" CssClass="input" placeholder="Enter Password" runat="server"/>

            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Remember me

            <asp:Hyperlink id="MyHyperLinkControl" NavigateUrl="http://google.com" runat="server">Forget password? </asp:Hyperlink>

            <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="button1Clicked" />

        </div>

</form>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Web.config file for fyp_codes.

The settings that can be used in this file are documented at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web and 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx
-->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies />
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please Help if you have any idea. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd guess that one of your images is not where the application is expecting it to be.

Comment: ASP.NET 4.x on Mono is not the right way to go. Please upgrade to ASP.NET Core, as it is the only supported approach to do cross platform development.

Answer (score 2):

In the error message it states the requested URL as "/":

> Details: Requested URL: /

but from the look of your ASPX mark up, you've called your page `Login.aspx`. Certain pages are often served by default e.g. index.html, index.aspx and default.aspx, which the web server is configured to look for, but Login.aspx isn't usually one of them.

Most likely this is the cause of the 404.

(There is also a missing closing `</head>` tag.. and although you say you haven't coded up your aspx.cs file yet, I assume one exists - the aspx page is inheriting from it - and at least has a stub out for the `button1Clicked` method referenced.)

Fixing these and explicitly requesting /Login.aspx worked for me:

[image]